# What does Dark Souls 3's Season Pass do?

Tags: steam, dark-souls-3

I'm fairly new to Season passes and how they work.

Looking at Steam today, I noticed that there's a great sale on Dark Souls 3 and it's DLCs. There are two alternatives:

- The base game and a Season Pass (which is cheaper) or,
- The base game and buy the two DLCs separately.

My questions is: what does the Season Pass do?

It says on the Steam page that the season pass allows one to *"gain access to 2 epic DLC packs at a discounted price"*. I assume this means that the season pass does not give me access to the DLCs and that I have to buy them separately?

Also the promised discount isn't included nor does it say if it works with the current sale.

Has anyone bought the season pass and tell me if its worth buying with the discounted price?

Comment: See also: [What is a season pass?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/85406/28182)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Season Pass *is* the two DLC. The wording is not perfectly clear, but by buying the Season Pass you don't gain access to the ability to buy DLC at a discounted price, you gain access to the DLC itself, at a lower price than buying them individually.

Incidentally, if you wanted to buy both Dark Souls III and the Season Pass, [this package](https://store.steampowered.com/sub/94174/) would be the cheapest option on Steam right now.

Comment: So let me see if I got this correctly: I don't get the DLCs when I buy the season pass. But I get to buy them at a lower price than if I bought them separately.

Comment: No - as Wrigglenite wrote, by buying the Season Pass, "you gain access to the DLC itself", "you don't gain access to the ability to buy DLC at a discounted price". You **will** get both DLC's when buying the SP.

Comment: In case you get notified and can confirm for me, if I have Dark Souls 3 with one DLC already (humble monthly, over a year ago), then season pass has no appeal to me (I do believe there won't be more DLCs to DS3)?

Answer (score 2):

Season Passes usually offer all current and future DLC in one, often discounted, package. Unlike GOTY deals, for example, they do not include the base game.

**The Dark Souls III Season Pass gives you both the *Ashes of Ariandel* DLC and *The Ringed City* DLC.**

Comment: I'd be wary of saying "all future DLC" - I know you prefaced it with 'usually' but a Season Pass tends to last for a set time period - a year for example - after which any future DLC will probably not be included.